# Do I have to define an event in this case?

Tags: c#, events

I've got a form with several controls (to make things simple, say it's a couple of textboxes), which I need to be updated by clicking on two buttons - a Forward button and a Backwards button.

Now, the general idea is that the information to be displayed is stored in some kind of array of objects, and is shown according to the value of some counter. That is, a user clicks on the Forward button -> the counter is incremented -> the corresponding array item is shown on the form. Same goes for the Backwards button.

So, the question is - should I define any specific event in this case? Or is it sufficient to use the standard

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

event which is provided when double-clicking on a button control? I mean, what would be the right thing to do?

I think it's a pretty dumb question, still I appreciate your advice here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's WinForms I'm talking about, should have mentioned it in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event is an ok place for that logic, however, it's a good practice to extract that forward/backward logic in a separate method (maybe you'll want to go forward by pressing the right arrow?) to something like this:

```
private void btnForward_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  GoForward();
} 

private void GoForward()
{
  // the forwarding code here
}
```

And, make a habit of naming controls as early as possible, because VS uses the control name to name the event handler, and `button1_Click` is not very descriptive :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I also thought of moving the code to a separate method in this case, just wanted to know about that event thing. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for separating the *what* (the concrete work to perform) from the *why* (the reason the work should be carried out; the event in this case).